# Custom error validation for Step property in HTML Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, dom, razor

I need to provide a custom validation message for when user input invalidates the `step = ".01"`

Currently, the validation message is the default "Please enter a multiple of 0.01".  How can I change this?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CostChanges[i].MyVariable, new { @class = "form-control", step = ".01" })
<span asp-validation-for="@Model.CostChanges[i].MyVariable" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo(remove `<span></span>` in your code,and use a new span to put your error message):

html:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CostChanges[i].MyVariable, new { @class = "form-control", step = ".01", onblur = "check(this)",type="number" })
            <span id="CostChanges_@(i)__MyVariable-error" class="text-danger field-validation-valid"></span>
```

js:

```
function check(input) {
        if ($(input).attr("aria-invalid")) {
            var id = $(input).attr("id") + "-error";
            //put your custom error message to the text
            $("#"+id).text("custom error message");
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]